# How can I add new data to an angular-chart.js chart (instead of updating existing data)?

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I would like to use a Chart.js line chart to show "live" data.  Using vanilla Chart.js, this can be done be calling the `.addData()` and `.removeData()` functions.  Here's an example:

http://jsbin.com/yitep/5/edit?html,js,output

How can I accomplish this "live data" effect using [`angular-chart.js`](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)?  If I update the bound data, the chart simply updates the existing data (it doesn't slide to the left to reveal new data).  It is the same effect as manually updating a Chart.js `dataset` and calling the `.update()` function in vanilla Chart.js, like this:

http://jsbin.com/yitep/4/edit?html,js,output

`angular-chart.js`'s documentation seems to only include examples of updating existing data points, not adding new data points.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Mine works with append but it redraws whole chart anyway.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. In my case I appended my data and turned off animations.

Comment: Yeah. I did the same thing.